# Swapping indices of two elements in a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Assuming a vector of objects, is it possible to swap the indices of two elements? Swapping two elements at positions `i` and `j` is straightforward:

```
tmp=vec[i];
vec[i]=vec[j];
vec[j]=tmp;
```

The above, however, makes use of the assignment operator `=` and depends on the objects stored in `vec` and the way the assignment operator is defined. In addition, it involves the creation of a new object `tmp` so I assume that pointers directed to the vector elements could be invalidated. My question is, is it possible to keep the objects stored at `i` and `j` and only swap their indices, so that after the operation `vec[i]` points to the object originally found at `vec[j]` and the other way around?

Comment: Unless you have a vectors of pointers (or references) you can't make an array index "reference" another object.

Comment: Also, whenever you need to swap something use [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). If that's not enough (which it should be in the vast majority of use-cases) then you have to tell us what problem you're really trying to solve, and what requirements you have, and why or how `std::swap` doesn't fulfill the requiremnts.

Comment: the objects themselves contain internal references which apparently are not straightforward to keep when copying. This is the reason I'd prefer not to touch the existing objects. Swapping is necessary because I am doing parallel tempering/replica exchange simulations. I guess I could set up a second vector with pointers to vec[] elements and do the swapping there.

Comment: @Botond "*the objects themselves contain internal references which apparently are not straightforward to keep when copying*" - that is why **move semantics** (via move constructors, move assignment operators, and rvalue references) were invented in C++11.  Your manual swap would then be `tmp = std::move(vec[i]); vec[i] = std::move(vec[j]); vec[j] = std::move(tmp);` No copying at all, if the objects are moveable. Though `std::swap()` should be used instead: `std::swap(vec[i], vec[j]);`